# Spring-Security + SAML: authorize multiple applications acting as a single service provider

Tags: spring, spring-security, jboss, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

We are currently developing an application for a customer. The project has the restriction that we shall deliver only deployable WAR files. The customer provides the infrastructure and doesn't allow much deviation from it.

The application is developped with Spring Boot, Spring Security and SAML. The current version is a single monolithic WAR file.

At the moment, we are in the process of splitting this monolithic application in separate applications because of multiple reasons (maintainability, deployment, code quality, ...). Unfortunately we do not know yet how to implement authorization with these given restrictions:

---

**Infrastructure constraints:**

- Applications will be deployed on JBoss EAP 7.0
- A custom Identity Provider is provided by the customer
- Communication with IdP has to be implemented with SAML 2.0

---

**The custom IdP has the following restrictions:**

- Authentication is done through a proxy, which means only authenticated users arrive at the application
- Only one SP metadata file can be provided, because it is linked to the user database. We want to share the same user database for all applications.
- The SP metadata file can only provide one AssertionConsumerService-Location
- The AssertionConsumerService-Location is statically defined in the metadata file and cannot be overriden in an AuthnRequest

---

**Problem description:**

Each application has to authorize itself with the IdP to receive roles and assertions. With the current (monolithic) deployment this is no problem as we require only a single AssertionConsumerService. With the new architecture, each application is able to redirect to the IdP, but the IdP can only redirect to the statically configured ACS. How can each application receive the AuthnResponse, when only a single ACS is possible?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From SAML-standards point of view this could be achieved with an SAML IdP Proxy. Your apps, acting as the ServiceProviders only communicate with the IdP part of the IdP Proxy. The actual IdP only communiates with the SP apart of the IdP Proxy (so there is only a single ACS url).

Comment: Yes that sounds like a possible solution. But implementing an own IdP sounds like a lot of work. Do you know of any existing libraries that already do this?

Comment: I'm not aware there is a single library which implements an IdP proxy, but there are some projects/products which offer this functionality. Still it's some additional infrastructure component to be deployed, maintained and operated, but it's the only standards-based approach which I know is working fine

Comment: I ran across this while investigating the same problem - I've not tried it out, but https://github.com/OpenConext/OpenConext-idensys appears to be a Java based SAML proxy which might offer a way forward.